# WiFi Speed suddenly dropped by 50%; Ethernet speed unchanged

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

During the May this year, my WiFi (5GHz) speed has suddenly dropped from 600mbps to 250mbps and it didn't get better ever since. (Plan is 600 / 600)

My original assumption was that the speed decreased because of the new router firmware. Today I proved that it was not the case.

I received a new router and bridged it with an old one. There was no improvement in the WiFi speed, but the Ethennet speed was 600 Mbps.

What could be the problem? Or better to ask, what else could I try? Considering that everything was fine before May?

Things I've tried:

- Use every available 5GHz channel
- Place laptop next to the router and perform the speed test
- Disable the main router's WiFi (both 2GHz and 5GHz)
- Running a Wireless Diagnostic on Mac
- Use Cloudefare's DNS - 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1

The wireless diagnostic resulted in this (Note: I'm in Spain):

> The following nearby networks conflict with your current country code
>   (es): Tenda_DD4 (xx:xx:xx) - US, PortaOne (xx:xx:xx) - DE

The Tenda router is my new router I connected to during the diagnostic.

ISP Contracted Speed: 600mbps

Main Router: [ZTE F680](https://www.balticnetworks.com/docs/ZTE_F680_brochure_20140715_EN.pdf) 
(802.11b/g/n @ 2.4GHz (3x3) or 802.11a/n/ac Wi-Fi @ 5GHz (3x3))

New Router: [Tenda AC1200 V1](https://www.tendacn.com/us/product/specification/AC6.html) [manual](http://down.tendacn.com/uploadfile/2017/User%20Guide/AC6_User_Guide.rar)

Speed tests done on 2018 15' MacBook Pro and iPhone XS Max

**UPDATE**:

With Wifi Analysis app I found this information:

1. I am the only one using the channel 161 (-40dbM)
2. My frequency is 5805MHz, and there are 3 neighbor WiFi access points in the range of 5300MHz - 5560MHz

Comment: Please forgive my asking, but are you in Spain, Germany, or the United Snakes? And, is the drop in performance replicated when you disable WiFi on your router and use an Ethernet cable to connect instead?

Comment: @K7AAY I am in Spain. The performance is not affected while using the ethernet cable.

Comment: Have you gotten in touch with your ISP?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, multiple times. They deny to send me a technician as they don't detect any anomalies.

Comment: 1) Your neighbors with the WiFi networks PortaOne & Tenda_DD4 have their routers set up as if they are not in Spain; different nations may use different WiFi frequencies. 2) Ethernet speed is unaffected, and only WiFi speed dropped, so someone else's WiFi or radio device causing interference is the likely cause. Is the Tenda router v1 or v2? Please advise. 3) Can you put a WiFi analysis app on a smartphone and find what frequencies are uses by _all_ your neighbors? Please advise.

Comment: Romen's absolutely right; most WiFi frequencies are in the Industrial, Scientific, and Medical bands, where frequencies are unlicensed and rarely regulated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band You're limited to transmit at around half a watt; with my amateur band license, I can transmit at up to 1,500 watts.

Comment: @K7AAY I've edited the question with the answers. Regarding the router version, it's v1.